# Validate on the name created via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the form inside the Jquery-UI-Dialog.
I understand of how to validate all field in the form.
Using the plugin of this [site](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#dialog').validate({
        rules: {
            category:
            {
                required: true
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            if ($('#ccategory').val() == 0){
                document.getElementById('choose_own_text').innerHTML  = "Please change here";
                return false;}
         //   console.log($('#ccategory').val());
            alert('valid form'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

But I have the `id` and `name` that I created via Javascript.
For example `id="inputp"+j+"_id"` where j is a number.

Now I want to validate this field but i have the error:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

I use this method because I declare with the number the data.

How to correct this error for that I can use always this technique's validate.

```
 $( "#wnd_Add" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 'auto',
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                resizable:false,
                buttons: {
                    "Add": function() {
                    var j=(parseInt(contapara)+1);
                    $('#formparam').validate({
                    rules: {
                    "inputp"+j+"_id":
                    {
                     required: true
                     },
                     },
                     submitHandler: {
                                     contapara=(parseInt(contapara)+1);

                    document.getElementById("sorpara").innerHTML+="<li id=\"inputp"+contapara+"_id\" class=\"ui-state-default\"><span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s\"></span>"+$('#inputp'+contapara+'_id').val()+"</li>";   

                    var $fm = $("#formparam");
                    $.get($fm.attr('${nextstep}'))
                        .done(function(data, ok){
                        var fr=$fm.serialize();
                        fr=fr.replace(/\&/g,"+%23+");
                        fr=replacew(fr,/\=/g, "%24+"); // //fr=fr.replace(/\=/g,"%24+");
                                        if(document.getElementById("inputp"+contapara+"_visible").checked==false)
                                          fr=fr+"+%23+inputp"+contapara+"_visible%24+off";
                        // data is the content of the response
                        document.location.href="index2?"+fr;})
                        .fail(function(data){
                        alert('call failed');
                        // call failed for some reason -- add error messaging?
                        });

    //                                 $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 

                                     return false;  },
                                     },

                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                close: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            });
```

I created a demo on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/H3tMS/) but not function because I have this error but may help

I hope the title of the question is correct...

UPDATE:

Now I have this script but I have the error `SyntaxError: missing : after property id` on

```
function(form)    {
```

This is last script:

```
$( "#wnd_Addparam" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 'auto',
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                resizable:false,
                buttons: {
                    "Add": function() {
                    var j=(parseInt(contapara)+1);
                    var rules= {};
                    rules["inputp" + j + "_id"]=
                    {
                     required: true
                     };
                    $('#formparam').validate({
                    rules: rules,
                     submitHandler: {
                     function(form)    {
                                     contapara=(parseInt(contapara)+1);

                    document.getElementById("sorpara").innerHTML+="<li id=\"inputp"+contapara+"_id\" class=\"ui-state-default\"><span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s\"></span>"+$('#inputp'+contapara+'_id').val()+"</li>";   

                    var $fm = $("#formparam");
                    $.get($fm.attr('${nextstep}'))
                        .done(function(data, ok){
                        var fr=$fm.serialize();
                        fr=fr.replace(/\&/g,"+%23+");
                        fr=replacew(fr,/\=/g, "%24+"); // //fr=fr.replace(/\=/g,"%24+");
                                        if(document.getElementById("inputp"+contapara+"_visible").checked==false)
                                          fr=fr+"+%23+inputp"+contapara+"_visible%24+off";
                        // data is the content of the response
                        document.location.href="index2?"+fr;})
                        .fail(function(data){
                        alert('call failed');
                        // call failed for some reason -- add error messaging?
                        });

                                     return false; } },
                                     });
                                     },

                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                close: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            });
```

Comment: George I change the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a variable as a key in a object like that, instead you can do something like

```
var rules = {};
rules["inputp"+j+"_id"] = {
    required: true
};
$('#formparam').validate({
    rules: rules,
    submitHandler: {
```

Ex;

```
var contapara = 3;
var regex, v, l, c, b;
$("#wnd_Addparam").dialog({
    autoOpen : false,
    height : 'auto',
    width : 350,
    modal : true,
    resizable : false,
    buttons : {
        "Add" : function() {
            var j = (parseInt(contapara) + 1);

            var rules = {};
            rules["inputp" + j + "_id"] = {
                required : true
            };

            $('#formparam').validate({
                rules : rules,
                submitHandler : function(form) {
                    contapara = (parseInt(contapara) + 1);

                    document.getElementById("sorpara").innerHTML += "<li id=\"inputp"
                            + contapara
                            + "_id\" class=\"ui-state-default\"><span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s\"></span>"
                            + $('#inputp' + contapara + '_id').val() + "</li>";

                    var $fm = $("#formparam");
                    $.get($fm.attr('${nextstep}')).done(function(data, ok) {
                        var fr = $fm.serialize();
                        fr = fr.replace(/\&/g, "+%23+");
                        fr = replacew(fr, /\=/g, "%24+"); // //fr=fr.replace(/\=/g,"%24+");
                        if (document.getElementById("inputp" + contapara
                                + "_visible").checked == false)
                            fr = fr + "+%23+inputp" + contapara
                                    + "_visible%24+off";
                        // data is the content of the response
                        document.location.href = "index2?" + fr;
                    }).fail(function(data) {
                        alert('call failed');
                            // call failed for some reason -- add error
                            // messaging?
                        });
                    return false;
                }
            })
        },

        Cancel : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close : function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
});

$("#btn_Addpar").click(function() {
    i = (parseInt(contapara) + 1);
    $("#formparam").remove();
    $("#wnd_Addparam")
            .append('<form method="GET" name="formparam"  id="formparam" action="${nextstep}">\
    <input type="hidden" name="json_data" value="${json_data}">\
    <input type="hidden" name="tag" value="${tag}">\
    <table><tr><td><label>ID</label></td><td>\
    <textarea class="expand" name="inputp'
                    + i
                    + '_id" id="inputp'
                    + i
                    + '_id"></textarea></td></tr>\
    <tr><td><label>Type</label></td><td><select name="inputp'
                    + i
                    + '_type" id="inputp'
                    + i
                    + '_type">\
    <option value="text">Text</option><option value="integer">Integer</option><option value="float">Float</option>\
    <option value="list_values">List of values</option><option value="range">Range</option>\
    <option value="selection_collapsed">Selection (collapsed)</option>\
    <option value="selection_expanded">Selection (expanded)</option>\
    <option value="subimage">Subimage selection</option>\
    <option value="polygon">Polygon selection</option>\
    <option value="horizontal_separator">Horizontal separator</option>\
    </select></td></tr><tr><td><label> Description</label></td>\
    <td><textarea class="expand" name="inputp'
                    + i
                    + '_description" id="inputp'
                    + i
                    + '_description"></textarea></td></tr>\
    <tr><td><label>Value</label></td><td><textarea class="expand" name="inputp'
                    + i
                    + '_value" id="inputp'
                    + i
                    + '_value"></textarea></td></tr>\
    <tr><td><label>Info (help)</label></td><td><textarea class="expand" id="inputp'
                    + i
                    + '_info" name="inputp'
                    + i
                    + '_info"></textarea></td></tr>\
    <tr><td><label> Visible?</label></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="inputp'
                    + i
                    + '_visible" name="inputp'
                    + i
                    + '_visible" checked></td></tr></table></form>');

    $("#wnd_Addparam").dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: Now I try... Thank for the suggest

Comment: Arun... get the error **SyntaxError: invalid label** 

  rules["inputp"+j+"_id"]:

Comment: Now get the error **SyntaxError: missing : after property id**  

function(form)    {

Comment: Before I wrong rules["inputp"+j+"_id"] : { required:true } because I put : that =

Comment: Before, without the technique's validate, the script works (Then the code is correct) and now that I would to use the validate not work.

Comment: Arun now work but I have the error **TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function**, I think is better that I created new question.
I delete { and } after **sumbitHanler:**

Comment: check whether you have included the validator plugin properly

Comment: jaaaaa but I don't know which is the latest version for use **$("").validate();** ?

Comment: Thank for help.. I check your answer because this is helpful.
The library is http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js
Now I created other question because I have the error **TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function**
Thank much, but I can receive the you up-vote on my question?